# Must declare the scalar variable error in subselect SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, declare, scalar

I am trying to create a SQL script that will create a nice easy to update script where another person only needs to update the constants involved and then run a query, however I an getting into trouble when using declared variables in sub selects.

I know this is because the declared variables are not in scope of the sub select but cant seem to nut out a workaround.

Here is the code currently:

```
DECLARE @_logdb varchar(30) = 'nb_tablename';
DECLARE @_sitedb varchar(30) = 'nb_tablename_site';
DECLARE @_backtodate varchar(30) = '2012-10-10';
DECLARE @_sitename varchar(50) = 'bikehaven';

UPDATE
    [@_sitedb].[dbo].[bike] 
SET [bikeStatus] = 'active' 
WHERE bikeID in (
    SELECT 
substring(
    [event], 
    CHARINDEX('bike ID' , [event]) + LEN('bike ID '),
    CHARINDEX(
        ')', 
        [event],
        CHARINDEX('bike ID' , [event])
    ) - (CHARINDEX('bike ID' , [event]) + LEN('bike ID '))
) as 'ID'
from [@_logdb].[dbo].[logs] 
where 
    user_name = 'john' AND 
    event_type = 'Deleted bike' AND 
    CHARINDEX('bike ID' , [event]) > 0 AND 
    date_time > @_backtodate AND 
    siteID = (
        SELECT id 
        from [@_logdb].[dbo].[sites] 
        WHERE site_name = @_sitename
    )
)
```

The two variables that are actually causing trouble are `@_backtodate` & `@_sitename`, but I also know if I substitute those variables with the real string I then get errors saying that `[@_sitedb].[dbo].[bike]` is also a problem.

Ive done a fair bit of googling, tried using temporary tables for the sub queries as well as defining the SQL as a variable itself and then running an `EXEC` command on it, but to no avail.

**Edit:** I've applied the change as directed by [Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50552/andomar) by pulling out the query itself into a declare variable and then running that, which was indeed the fix for one of the errors, however even with that fix I am still getting Must define scalar variable errors for `@_back to date` & `@_sitename`.

**Solution:**  The change suggested by [Alexander Fedorenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085940/alexander-fedorenko) ended up giving me the last bit of the puzzle. Which was table names cannot be used as explicit replacements via parameters in dynamic SQL, where these work perfectly for *actual* variable values.

In Short:
- Make the query a string variable.
- Any table name replacements that need to occur you can add via string concatenations (meaning the output string needs to be a valid query)
- Pass any variable parameters for substitution to the stored procedure `SP_executesql`

The final working code is as specified by [Alexander Fedorenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085940/alexander-fedorenko).

Comment: "this is because the declared variables are not in scope of the sub select" - no, it's not. You've mis-diagnosed the issue. As @Andomar points out, the main issue is you can't use string variables in places where SQL Server expects to encounter a name (such as in the names of tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

procedure sp_executesql allows use parameters. [Using sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
DECLARE @_logdb varchar(30) = 'nb_tablename';
DECLARE @_sitedb varchar(30) = 'nb_tablename_site';
DECLARE @_backtodate varchar(30) = '2012-10-10';
DECLARE @_sitename varchar(50) = 'bikehaven';

DECLARE @_SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @_SQL = '
UPDATE
    ' + @_sitedb + '.[dbo].[bike] 
SET [bikeStatus] = ''active'' 
WHERE bikeID in (
    SELECT 
substring(
  [event],
CHARINDEX(''bike ID'' , [event]) + LEN(''bike ID ''),
CHARINDEX(
'')'', 
[event],
CHARINDEX(''bike ID'' , [event])
) - (CHARINDEX(''bike ID'' , [event]) + LEN(''bike ID ''))
) as ''ID''
from ' + @_logdb + '.[dbo].[logs]
where 
user_name = ''john'' AND 
event_type = ''Deleted bike'' AND
CHARINDEX(''bike ID'' , [event]) > 0 AND
date_time > @_backtodate AND
siteID = (
SELECT id 
from ' + @_logdb + '.[dbo].[sites]
WHERE site_name = @_sitename
    )
)'
EXEC sp_executesql @_SQL, N'@_backtodate varchar(30), @_sitename varchar(50)', @_backtodate, @_sitename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a variable as table name.  So this won't work:

```
from [@_logdb].[dbo].[logs]
```

If you really want variable table names, the only option is dynamic SQL.  Create an `nvarchar(max)` variable with the SQL, and run it with `sp_executesql` or `exec`.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from ' + @tablename
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: I've added your change which is great and solves my table name issue, however I'm still having issues with the `@_backtodate` & `@_sitename` variables.